# Geometric representation of product rule?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, intuition

At time 1:06 of [this video by minutephysics](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNReoaONJdg&t=1m6s), there is a geometric representation of the product rule:

[image]

However, I don't understand how the sums of the areas of those thin strips represent $d(u\cdot v)$. The only way I can see it is that $d(u\cdot v)$ is a small change in the area of the square, and those thin strips do represent that; however, I'm not sure if this is correct and if it is, how formal of a proof is this? Thanks!

Comment: How can a Youtube video be considered a formal proof?

Comment: You can link to a specific time in a Youtube video. Also, *always* take screenshots or copy down the information yourself into the question, so that your question will still make sense if external content is removed.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: I'm talking about the diagram, just like the phytagorean theorem was proved with a diagram by Bhaskara.  I really don't know if that was considered a formal proof, but I think it's pretty convincing.

Comment: @Zev Chonoles: Ok thanks I'll do that next time.

Comment: Also, it is not a square, but a rectangle. It will only confuse you if you think of it as a square.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: yeah my mistake

Comment: From your diagram, the area of the large rectangle is (u + dv)(v + du) = uv + u dv + v du + du dv. But du and dv are infinitesimal quantities, so the product du and dv, though also infinitesimal, is infinitesimally smaller than either du or dv, so we may disregard it. We have (u + du)(v + dv) = uv + d(uv) = uv + u dv + v du. Subtracting uv from both sides, we see that d(uv) = u dv + v du

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the picture of the rectangle in my own teaching (without the differential notation) and show it to grad students who are starting their teaching careers. It is far superior to the usual tricky addition-of-$0$ argument found in most textbooks.

Here is the argument in greater detail:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\Delta(uv)}{\Delta x} &= \frac{(u+\Delta u)(v+\Delta v) - uv}{\Delta x} \\
&= \frac{u\Delta v + v\Delta u + \Delta u\Delta v}{\Delta x} = u \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x} +
v \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \Delta u\cdot\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}\,.
\end{align*}
Taking $\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}$ gives the product rule.

This can all be written out with the usual $f(x+h)g(x+h)$ notation, if so desired.

By the way, this same picture can be used to give a more motivated proof of the product theorem for limits, as well.

Comment: One tiny little tweak I'd make is to replace the $\Delta u\cdot\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}$ at the end of the last line with a $\Delta x\cdot\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}\cdot\frac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}$ so it's immediately clear that that quantity goes to zero (as long as $u'$ and $v'$ are bounded, of course), as opposed to needing to argue that $\Delta u\to 0$ which can sometimes throw a wrench in the works.

Comment: Well, of course, that *is* the argument. But it doesn't hurt to remind folks that differentiability implies continuity, precisely by that argument :)